# How to make numpy overloading of __add__ independent on operand order?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, operator-overloading

I am facing an issue when overloading operators in a class containing a numpy array as attribute. Depending on the order of the operands, the result type will be my class A (desired behavior) or a numpy array. How to make it always return an instance of A?

Example:

```
import numpy as np

class A(object):
    """ class overloading a numpy array for addition
    """
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values

    def __add__(self, x):
        """ addition
        """
        x = np.array(x) # make sure input is numpy compatible
        return A(self.values + x)

    def __radd__(self, x):
        """ reversed-order (LHS <-> RHS) addition
        """
        x = np.array(x) # make sure input is numpy compatible
        return A(x + self.values)

    def __array__(self):
        """ so that numpy's array() returns values
        """
        return self.values

    def __repr__(self):
        return "A object: "+repr(self.values)
```

An instance of A:

```
>>> a = A(np.arange(5))
```

This works as expected:

```
>>> a + np.ones(5)  
A object: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
```

This does not:

```
>>> np.ones(5) + a
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
```

Even though this is fine:

```
>>> list(np.ones(5)) + a
A object: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
```

What happens in the second example is that radd is not called at all, and instead the numpy method `__add__` from np.ones(5) is called.

I tried a few suggestions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619449/how-can-i-override-comparisons-between-numpys-ndarray-and-my-type) but `__array_priority__` does not seem to make any difference (EDIT after seberg comment: at least in numpy 1.7.1, but could work on newer versions), and `__set_numeric_ops__` leads to Segmentation Fault... I guess I am doing something wrong.

Any suggestion that works on the simple example above (while keeping `__array__` attribute)?

EDIT: I do not want A to be a subclass of np.ndarray, since this would comes with other complications that I want to avoid - for now at least. Note that pandas seems to have got around this problem:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(5)) 
type(df.values + df) is pd.DataFrame  # returns True
isinstance(df, np.ndarray) # returns False
```

I'd be curious to know how this was done.

SOLUTION: in addition to M4rtini solution of subclassing, it is possible to add `__array_wrap__` attribute to the class A (to avoid subclassing). More [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html). According to seberg, `__array_priority__` could also work on newer numpy versions (see comment).

Comment: Add `__array_priority__` if you add `__array__`, not sure if that covers everything on older versions or not.

Comment: Is there a special way to do this? If I just add a class attribute     `__array_priority__ = 1000`, it does not solve the problem. I also tried with 0, -1 ... My numpy version is 1.7.1, which is quite recent, isn't it?

Comment: You were not far, `__array_wrap__` did the trick (see answer below)

Comment: Pretty recent, but not enough for what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @M4rtini and @seberg, it seems that adding `__array_wrap__` does solve the question:

```
class A(object):
    ...
    def __array_wrap__(self, result):
        return A(result)  # can add other attributes of self as constructor
```

It appears to be called at the end of any ufunc operation (it includes array addition). This is also how pandas does it (in 0.12.0, pandas/core/frame.py l. 6020).

Answer (score 5):

Make `A` a subclass of `np.ndarray` and Python will invoke your `A.__radd__` method *first*.

From the [`object.__radd__` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__):

> **Note**: If the right operand’s type is a subclass of the left operand’s type and that subclass provides the reflected method for the operation, this method will be called before the left operand’s non-reflected method. This behavior allows subclasses to override their ancestors’ operations.

By subclassing your `A` object is indeed able to intercept the addition:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> class A(np.ndarray):
...     """ class overloading a numpy array for addition
...     """
...     def __init__(self, values):
...         self.values = values
...     def __add__(self, x):
...         """ addition
...         """
...         x = np.array(x) # make sure input is numpy compatible
...         return A(self.values + x)
...     def __radd__(self, x):
...         """ reversed-order (LHS <-> RHS) addition
...         """
...         x = np.array(x) # make sure input is numpy compatible
...         return A(x + self.values)
...     def __array__(self):
...         """ so that numpy's array() returns values
...         """
...         return self.values
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "A object: "+repr(self.values)
... 
>>> a = A(np.arange(5))
>>> a + np.ones(5)  
A object: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
>>> np.ones(5) + a
A object: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
```

Do study the [Subclassing `ndarray` documenation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#basics-subclassing) for caveats and implications.

Comment: Thanks, but I was actually hoping not having to subclass, as the class in question is quite large and would present incompatibilities (here FYI: https://github.com/perrette/dimarray). I note that pandas DataFrame did go around this problem, so I guess there is another solution.

Comment: @Mahé I'm pretty sure that the pandas DataFrame actually is a subclass of numpy.ndarray. And if not, you could go through the pandas source and see how they did it.

Comment: @M4rtini It is not...Try isinstance(pd.DataFrame(), np.ndarray) or issubclass(pd.DataFrame, np.ndarray), they will return False. I was wondering if there was an obvious answer, but if not, yes, I will look through the source, and share the answer here.

Comment: @Mahé Looks like it changed with version 0.13 of pandas. [source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#v0-13-0-january-3-2014)  "In 0.13.0 Series has internally been refactored to no longer sub-class ndarray but instead subclass NDFrame, similar to the rest of the pandas containers."

Comment: Ah yes, I remember reading that. See final answer below, after checking in the code. From the numpy doc I thought `__array_wrap__` was only for subclass, but it appears to work as soon as `__array__` is present.

Comment: ...but accepted the answer as valid. The solution I was looking for is now edited in the question, and also below (not sure what's standard in this case).

Answer (score 0):

@Martijn Pieters does not seem to work as there are special rules for subclassing an nparray (see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.subclassing.html)) including using `__new__` instead of `__init__` and using `__array_finalize__`.

Here is the code that works for me:

```
import numpy as np

class Abstract_Array(np.ndarray):
    """ class overloading a numpy array for addition
    """
    def __new__(cls, input_array):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        return None

    def __add__(self, x):
        """ addition
        """
        x = np.array(x) # make sure input is numpy compatible
        return Abstract_Array(addfunc(self,x)) # define your own add function

    def __radd__(self, x):
        """ reversed-order (LHS <-> RHS) addition
        """
        x = np.array(x) # make sure input is numpy compatible
        return Abstract_Array(raddfunc(self,x))

    def __array__(self):
        """ so that numpy's array() returns values
        """
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Abstract_Array object of shape %s: \n %s" % (str(self.shape), str(self)[:100])
```