# Python class sum with numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, class, numpy, overriding

I have a question concerning overriding operands. I just tried to override the `__add__(self, other)` operator in a custom class, such that on of its elements (a numpy array) can be added to another numpy array. To make both directions of summing possible I both declared the `__add__`as well as the `__radd__` operator. A small example:

```python
import numpy as np

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self._mat = self._calc_mat()


    def _calc_mat(self):
        return np.eye(2)*self.x

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self._mat + other

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self._mat + other


def some_function(x):
    return x + np.ones(4).reshape((2,2))

def some_other_function(x):
    return np.ones(4).reshape((2,2)) + x


inst = MyClass(3)

some_function(x=inst)
some_other_function(x=inst)
```

Strangely, I get two different outputs. The first ouput, from `some_function` is just like expected:

```python
Out[1]
array([[ 4.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  4.]])
```

The second output gives me something odd:

```python
Out[2]:    
array([[array([[ 4.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  4.]]),
        array([[ 4.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  4.]])],
       [array([[ 4.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  4.]]),
        array([[ 4.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  4.]])]], dtype=object)
```

Does somebody have an idea why is that?
Thanks, Markus :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is that numpy array is also implementing an `__add__` method, and it is called before your `__radd__`

you can see this answer for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22633052/7033869