# Numpy - Matrix multiplication to return ndarray, not sum

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

All, I have an application that requires returning a numpy ndarray, rather than a simple sum, when multiplying two matrices; e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]])
y = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]])
w = x @ y
>>> array([[2, 0, 1, 1],
           [1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

However, the requirement is to return an ndarray (in this case..):

```
array([[[1,1,0], [0,0,0], [0,1,0], [1,0,0]],
       [[0,1,0], [0,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,0]]])
```

Note that the matrix multiplication operation may be repeated; the output will be used as the left-side matrix of ndarrays for the next matrix multiplication operation, which would yield a higher-order ndarray after the second matrix multiplication operation, etc..

Any way to achieve this? I've looked at overloading `__add__`, and `__radd__` by subclassing np.ndarray [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632937/how-to-make-numpy-overloading-of-add-independent-on-operand-ordee), but mostly got dimension incompatibility errors.

Ideas?

**Update:**

Addressing @Divakar's answer E.g., for chained operation, adding

```
z = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]])
s1 = x[...,None] * y
s2 = s1[...,None] * z
```

results in an undesired output.

I suspect the issue starts with s1, which in the case above returns s1.shape = (2,3,4). It should be (2,4,3) since [2x3][3x4] = [2x4], but we're not really summing here, just return an array of length 3.

Similarly, s2.shape should be (2,3,4,3), which [incidentally] it is, but with undesired output (it's not 'wrong', just not what we're looking for). 
To elaborate, s1*z should be [2x4][4x3] = [2x3] matrix. Each element of the matrix is itself an ndarray, of [4x3] since we have 4 rows in z to multiply the elements in s1, and each element in s1 is itself 3 elements long (again, we're not arithmetically adding elements, but return ndarrays with the extended dimension being the row count in the R-matrix of the operation.

Ultimately, the desired output would be:

```
s2 = array([[[[1, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0]],

              [[1, 1, 0],
               [0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0],
               [1, 0, 0]],

              [[0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0]]],


             [[[0, 1, 0],
               [0, 0, 0],
               [0, 1, 0],
               [0, 0, 0]],

              [[0, 1, 0],
               [0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0]],

              [[0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0]]]])
```

Comment: That looks more like an outer product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extend them to `3D` and leverage `broadcasting` -

```
x[:,None] * y.T
```

Or with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ij,jk->ikj',x,y)
```

---

Going by [`OP's comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47974959/numpy-matrix-multiplication-to-return-ndarray-not-sum#comment82919442_47975002) and the quote from the question :

> ... matrix multiplication operation may be repeated; the output will
>   be used as the left-side matrix of ndarrays for the next matrix
>   multiplication operation, which would yield a higher-order ndarray
>   after the second matrix multiplication operation, etc..

It seems, we need to do something along these lines -

```
s1 = x[...,None] * y
s2 = s1[...,None] * z # and so on.
```

Though, the order of the axes would be different in this case, but it seems to be the simplest way to extend the solution to a generic number of incoming `2D` arrays.

Following the edits in the question, seems like you are placing the incoming arrays from the first axis onwards for element-wise multiplication. So, if I got that right, you can swap axes to get the correct order, like so -

```
s1c = (x[...,None] * y).swapaxes(1,-1)
s2c = (s1c.swapaxes(1,-1)[...,None] * z).swapaxes(1,-1) # and so on.
```

If you are only interested in the final output, swap axes only at the final stage and skip those in the intermediate ones.

Comment: @Divakar, thanks, but this doesn't chain properly; e.g.: defining this 4x3 matrix `z = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]])` and assuming s1 is the output from your answer, the following chained operation `s1[:, None] * z.T` throws the following error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,1,4,3) (3,4)`.

Comment: @GG_Python Well then you need to do `z *s1`. Thus, the further operations after obtaining `s1` would depend on the shapes of the incoming arrays.

Comment: @GG_Python Or what exactly is the expected output from multiplying `z` and `s1`? Could you add the expected output?

Comment: How about `x[..., None, :] * y.T`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer `s1 = x[..., None, :] * y.T` and then `s2 = s1[..., None, :] * z.T`?

Comment: Yep, the invariant would be that the last dimension of the left factor and the first of the right  are equal and fixed (and that the right is 2D). OP's description could be interpreted that way.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Yeah, but `s1[..., None, :] * z.T` doesn't work for `s1 = x[..., None, :] * y.T `, shape mis-match there.

Comment: Oh, that `z`; I thought that was only to show what is not wanted? Anyway, you'll have to wait for OP's word.

Comment: @Divakar, please see edits above for clarification. Thx!